# Android MVVM design pattern: to which layer do the activity/fragment belong?

Tags: android, mvvm

I'm studying Android MVVM design pattern but I can't understand the right collocation of activity and fragment. It is correct to say that activity/fragment belong to the View layer?

Comment: MVVM is Model View ViewModel. As the name suggests view is responsible for displaying UI to the ther user and Model to hold data. Activity / fragment display UI to the user so it is in View.

Answer (score 0):

MVVM is Model View ViewModel, an architecture and design method
when you talk about View layer for example in clean Architecture, you have this schema :

```
 View Layer             |    domain Layer       |      data Layer 
Activity/fragment       | UseCase / Repository  | Api/DAO/RespositoryImpl
viewModel               |                       |
```

[image]